# SQL like operator: append wildcard to column in result set (on SAP HANA database)

Tags: sql

<strike>I have a SQL statement like the following:</strike>

```
select A from table1, (select B from table2) where A like B
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to append wildcard '%' to B in the where statement, like:

```
where A like B%
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I'm working on SAP HANA database, I figured out the correct syntax, it is:

```
where A like B || '%'
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but the syntax varies from database to database.

**SQL Server**

```
WHERE A LIKE (B + '%')
```

**Oracle**

```
WHERE A LIKE (B || '%')
```

**MySQL / Postgres**

```
WHERE A LIKE CONCAT(B, '%')
```